# Weathermap API not able to parse completely in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm able to retrieve data from the weather map api, however I can't figure out how to exactly parse the data. I'm able to do it only for a certain part of it.

This is the JSON data:

```
{
    base = "cmc stations";
    clouds =     {
        all = 56;
    };
    cod = 200;
    coord =     {
        lat = "29.66";
        lon = "-82.3";
    };
    dt = 1403641995;
    id = 4156404;
    main =     {
        humidity = 74;
        pressure = 1018;
        temp = "304.08";
        "temp_max" = "306.48";
        "temp_min" = "302.15";
    };
    name = Gainesville;
    rain =     {
        3h = 0;
    };
    sys =     {
        country = US;
        message = "0.2087";
        sunrise = 1403605821;
        sunset = 1403656392;
    };
    weather =     (
                {
            description = "broken clouds";
            icon = 04d;
            id = 803;
            main = Clouds;
        }
    );
    wind =     {
        deg = 153;
        gust = "1.54";
        speed = "0.51";
    };
}
```

Now I am able to get only one part of it :
base = "cmc stations"

like this:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions 
                                                           error:&error];

    NSLog(@"values %@",json);

    NSLog(@"Checking values ------------ %@",[json objectForKey:@"cloud"]);


}
```

But when I try to do the same for other fields like
clouds
coord
main

I can't. I get a null value.

I'm guessing I need an additional NSDictionary or NSArray but just not sure how to go about it. Can someone please tell how can I do this?  I'm mainly looking to get data from the main block :

```
humidity
temp
temp_max
temp_min

rain

sunrise
sunset
```

I think I have found a solution:

Here's how I'm getting the data:

```
    NSString* base = [json objectForKey:@"base"];
    NSLog(@"Value of first base variable:      %@",base);

//    NSArray* base = [json objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *clouds = [json objectForKey:@"clouds"];
    NSLog(@"Value of first clouds‹ variable:    %@",clouds);

    NSArray *coord = [json objectForKey:@"coord"];
    NSLog(@"Value of first coord variable:      %@",coord);


    NSDictionary *main = [json objectForKey:@"main"];
    NSLog(@"Value of first coord variable:      %@",main);

    NSArray* humidity = [main objectForKey:@"humidity"];
    NSLog(@"humidity levels found manually : %@",humidity);

    NSArray* temp_max = [main objectForKey:@"temp_max"];
    NSLog(@"max temp levels found manually : %@",temp_max);
```

Comment: The data posted here does not look like JSON. Can you show an example of the actual raw JSON string represented by responseData?

Comment: Here's the API link:  

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=29.657955&lon=-82.301773

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that most of those values are dictionaries, not arrays. When you see `{` `}` and colons (`:`) that will generally indicate the presence of a dictionary of key-value pairs, even though some of them may only have one such pair which might make it appear like an array or a stand-alone object.

To get `clouds` for instance:

```
NSDictionary *clouds = [json objectForKey:@"clouds"];
NSNumber *allClouds = [clouds objectForKey:@"all"];
NSLog(@"Value of first clouds‹ variable:    %@",allClouds);
```

To get `coord`:

```
NSDictionary *coords = [json objectForKey:@"coord"];
NSNumber *lon = [coords objectForKey:@"lon"];
NSNumber *lat = [coords objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSLog(@"Value of lon is:      %@",lon);
```